# How to set label and input in one line?

Tags: css

Hi i have a diferent style because betwin labale and input set icon. Please lock at the https://jsfiddle.net/mL1o0d5m/

css codes :

```
body{
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    color:#999;
    direction:rtl;
}

.form{
    font-size:14px;
    width:100%;
}

.form label{
    text-align: right;
    clear: both;
    float:right;
}

.form input.inputs{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#999;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-right:none;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:80%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding:10px;
    padding-right:30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-shadow:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.addon{
    position:relative;
    font-size:0;
}

.addon:before{
    display:block;
    content:"";
    width:3px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#3399cc;
    position:absolute;
}

.icon:before{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#bbb;
    position:absolute;
    top:12px;
    right:12px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<form class="form">
<label>Name</label>
    <div class="addon">
        <i class="icon fa fa-user"></i>
        <input class="inputs" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>



</form>
```

I wanna to set label and input in same line .label should be in right and input and icon must be at left .
Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this? 
https://jsfiddle.net/mL1o0d5m/1/ 
it is one of the many posibilities to achieve this. Added some css
    `.form > label{
      text-align: right;
      float:right;
      width:40px;
      margin-top:10px;
 }`
and also to .icon:before and .addon:before
See in fiddle